# How to log websites accessed by device in my network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, logging

I'm trying to log all the websites accessed by the devices connected to my router

Dlink has this feature by default but it is limited to 40 pages with 10 items per page so it can store only 400 items. Each item has the following information `Web site superuser.com/posts/validate-body accessed from 192.x.x.x.`

So, is there any way to increase the storage limitation? Or is their any other way to log those details.

I tried opendns but I'm under a double nat, when I try to add my public ip in opendns it is giving a message `Network already exists`. so, I cannot use opendns or may be i don't know how to.

I'm using Dlink dir 803.

Comment: You need a router model with more memory and the ability to log more.

Comment: Alternative you could set up a proxy server and route all the traffic through that.

Comment: @Burgi do I need to have access to all devices or just my router

Answer (score 1):

Try wireshark,its a packet sniffer.
You can also try Cain & Abel if you want additional functionality.
C&A will generate a firewall warning though.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.manualslib.com/manual/864771/D-Link-Dir-803.html?page=102 the router has the ability to send the syslog to an external device that is running a syslog utility that can be used to store every request into a file or database - allowing you to keep much more of the logs. Syslog is real-time so you'll want the "database" server to be on all the time if you don't want to miss capturing any logs.

Unfortunately the manual page I've found doesn't have the instructions how to enable this but there will probably be a tab or page with the option to enable the syslog server and what LAN IP to send the logs to.